# Div not exactly equalling height of parent div with inherit value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 3 divs inside a parent div, intended to be arranged like so:

```
 ______________________________________
|                                      |
|                HEADER                |
|______________________________________|
 ____   _______________________________
|    | |                               |
|    | |                               |
|    | |                               |
|    | |                               |
| N  | |                               |
| A  | |            CONTENT            |
| V  | |                               |
| -  | |                               |
| B  | |                               |
| A  | |                               |
| R  | |                               |
|    | |                               |
|    | |                               |
|____| |_______________________________|
```

The `#header` is fixed height, so I'm having no issues with it.

However, the `#content` div's, well, content, is dynamic, depending on the page that is loaded. I want `#nav-bar` to match the height of `#content` at all times, but I haven't been able to manage it.

I want the min-height of `#content` and `#nav-bar` to be 100% of the screen height (so they take up the full height of the screen at minimum at all times), but then as `#content` grows beyond that, I want `#nav-bar` to grow accordingly.

I've gotten `#nav-bar`'s height to grow, but not at exactly the same value as `#content`, so their heights are still mismatched.

Here is the relevant code I have in place, and [the actual page in question is here](http://jaddl.clanteam.com/index2.php).

**HTML:**

```html
<div id='container'>
    <div id='center-panel'>
        <div id='top-banner'></div>
        <div id='nav-bar'>
            <?php
            echo get_nav_list();
            ?>
        </div>
        <div id='header'><span id='fact-tag'>current points leader</span><span id='fact-value'>4</span></div>
        <div id='content'>Lorem ipsum...
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
html, body {
    background-color: #ccc;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    font-family: 'Noto Sans', 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;
    color: #666;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
}

#center-panel {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 800px;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%;
}

#header {   /*top bar*/
    height: 33px;
    max-height: 33px;
    text-align: right;
    color: #aaa;
    padding: 0px 15px 0px 160px;
    font-size: 18pt;
    border: 2px dashed blue;
}

#header span#fact-tag {
    font-weight: 700;
}

#header span#fact-value {
    display: inline-block;
    min-width: 40px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    margin-left: 10px;
    color: #444;
    padding: 0px 3px 0px 3px;
}

#nav-bar {  /*left bar*/
    float: left;
    width: 110px;
    text-align: center;
    height: inherit;
    font-family: 'Oxygen', 'Tahoma', sans-serif;
    padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px;
    border: 2px dashed red;
}

#nav-bar ul {   /*main menu*/
    list-style-type: none;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 10pt;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#nav-bar > ul > li {    /*main menu item*/
    min-height: 35px;
    background-color: #444;
    color: #ccc;
    border-left: 6px solid #444;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #666;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-bar ul > li > ul { /*sub-menu*/
    display: none;
}

#nav-bar ul > li > ul > li {    /*sub-menu item*/
    min-height: 25px;
    background-color: #555;
    border-bottom: 3px solid #444;
    font-size: 10pt;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#nav-bar ul > li > ul > li > ul > li {  /*third-level menu item*/
    border: none;
    min-height: 10px;
    font-size: 8pt;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#content {  /*central content area*/
    padding: 60px 45px 30px 160px;
    border: 2px dashed green;
}
```

**Javascript:**

```js
$('#nav-bar ul li').on('click', function() {
    $(this).css('border-left-color', '#ad9557').siblings().css('border-left-color', '#666');
    $(this).children().slideDown('fast');
    $(this).siblings().children('ul').slideUp('fast');
});

$('#nav-bar').css('height', $('#container').height());
```

Comment: What browsers do you have to support?

Comment: Your example page and your ASCII drawing are inconsistent with the placement of the header - by 'header' in your ASCII drawing, do you mean the element '#top-banner'?

Comment: @robyaw The ascii drawing is my intended result, not what you actually see on the page today (hence, why I'm here asking for help). :)  Ignore #top-banner, it's fine and just adding some padding to the top of all elements within #center-panel.

Comment: @DerekHenderson I'd like to make it as cross-browser as possible, though the majority of my audience will be on modern browsers (Firefox, Chrome) or tablets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a great idea to use `display: table` or the `float` property for layout. Tables are for tabular data, and floats are designed to allow text to flow around them in paragraphs. You can easily solve this problem by assigning `position: absolute` to your `#navbar` element and adjusting a few properties elsewhere to make the layout act as desired.

```
#navbar {
    padding: 33px 0px 0px 0px;
    float: left;
}
```

```
#navbar {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
}
#container {
    position: relative;
}
#nav-bar ul {
    margin: 33px 0 0;
}
```

I changed the `margin` on `#nav-bar ul` because the navbar's padding was causing it to increase in height past the page's limit. If you need more info on absolute positioning, further reading can be done [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html).

This solution will work without javascript and will work on almost all browsers.

Edit: since you want the page to change depending on the height of the user's screen and the height of the `#content` div, you can use a jQuery one-liner to check to see if the `#content` div is tall enough or not.

```
($('#content').offset().top+$('#content').height() < $(window).height())?($('#content').height($(window).height()-90-$('#content').offset().top)):null;
```

This code is equivalent to saying "If the content div's height and offset is below the height of the window, increase the content div's height to exactly the height it needs to be to fill the window, otherwise do nothing."

Comment: Thanks, we're nearly there! Your solution works wonderfully as long as the content within #content is longer than the window. However, if you go check the site again now, I've shortened #content's length, and the whole of #center-panel and its children do not reach all the way down to the window height like they should...even though min-height is set to 100% for html, body, and #center-panel itself. Suggestions?

Comment: Oh, I see, you have a condition that states that the height of the page should be at a minimum the screen's height. Well, you'll have to use javascript for that, since `min-height` isn't really a conditional tool. I'd do something like `($('#content').offset().top+$('#content').height() < $(window).height())?($('#content').height($(window).height()-90-$('#content').offset().top)):;`, the value of `90` being the `top` and `bottom` padding value of `content`. Let me know if this ternary operator is confusing, I can explain it further.

Comment: OK, you got that part solved! One last thing: if you shrink your window and reload, then click `News` followed by either `2013` or `2014`, #nav-bar can now extend _past_ #content and #center-panel. So in that case, I'd need #center-panel to extend to match the height of #nav-bar...

Comment: Haha, oh god, this is becoming a whole mess of javascript. I didn't realize the nav was an accordion style expanding menu. You'll have to edit your `$(this).siblings().children('ul').slideUp('fast');` function to read `$(this).siblings().children('ul').slideUp('fast', function() { // resizing goes here});`, at this point I think you can figure out what code to use to resize your element!

Comment: Yeah sorry, you now see why something so simple got much more complicated, design-wise. :)  I'm guessing I need to put opposing code in the callback function of `$(this).children().slideDown('fast')` as well (to grow `#content` when the accordion grows), yes?

Comment: It looks like what you've done on your site is almost correct, I would define a function to return `true` or `false` depending on if the `#content` div is bigger than the screen, then use that function to determine whether or not the `#content` div should be resized. As of right now, it's being resized even when it shouldn't be.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31881/discussion-between-praguian-and-joey)

Answer (score 1):

Use `display:table`, that will force the height of the two columns to match, regardless of which is bigger.

Comment: Set `display: table` on which div?

Comment: #container, then set #header, #navbar, and #content to display: table-cell

Comment: This solution must require complete restructuring of my code, because that CSS alone destroys my layout and makes #nav-bar, #header, and #content into 3 page-long columns side by side (and #nav-bar _still_ isn't the same height as the others :) ).

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. I was able to get it to work on your page using the chrome dev tools. Anything that is a full row should be display:table-row, and you must specify the height property (min-height and max-height won't work). You can read up on this at [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSSref/pr_class_display.asp)

Comment: In response to the nice JS solution below, the reason I suggested using display: table for this is because of the accordion style expanding nav-bar. It will automatically adjust without any JS. @Joey is right though, not what tables are intended for...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have to support IE8, simply use `calc`:

```
#nav-bar,
#content {
    min-height: calc(100% - 33px); // 33px is height of header, of course
}
```

If you do have to support IE8, just set it with jQuery, as you're already using it:

```
$('#nav-bar, #content').css('min-height', ($(window).height() - 33) + 'px');
```

And if you want '#nav-bar' always to match the height of '#content', add this:

```
$('#nav-bar').css('height', $('#content').height() + 'px');
```

Another possibility is to use `flex-box`.

Comment: Your jquery doesn't work, and results in a similar output to my original code. #nav-bar's height grows, but not all the way to the height of #content (and #center-panel, the parent).

Comment: Your final jquery above is what I originally had. :)  It wasn't getting #nav-bar to match #content exactly. It was falling about 130 or so pixels short (and adding the 130px manually is not an option, as that makes #nav-bar _longer_ than #content in certain cases.

Comment: @praguian, it actually works just fine when you order your html correctly and account for the extra padding you've assigned in your CSS.  See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dMGne/.  But you might want to consider checking out flex-box.  Also, why are you not using html5's `<nav>` tag?

Comment: Derek, because I'm not familiar w/ HTML5 yet. :)

Comment: @praguian, that's as good an excuse as any, I guess. ;)  It's well worth the time familiarising yourself with html5. Took me forever to make the switch, but I'm glad I did.

Comment: I'll certainly do that. Whether I get to it on this project or not is simply a matter of available time!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Just add '!important':

```
$('#nav-bar').css('height', ($('#container').height()+'!important'));
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt [as a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LMVyd/). The bulk of the changes are in the CSS and HTML; the actual nav height setting is done almost identically to your posted code:

```
$('#nav-bar').css(
    'height',
     $('#content-container').height() - parseInt($('#nav-bar').css('border-width'), 10) * 2);
```

where `parseInt($('#nav-bar').css('border-width'), 10) * 2` is done to take into account the demo borders on `#nav-bar`; your solution probably won't need this in.